# JSONObject keySet() function not there?

Tags: java, android, json, keyset, missingmethod

Very confused.
New project, add this code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.keys();
jsonObject.keySet();
```

`.keys()` method resolves as it should.

`.keySet()` method highlights red with AndroidStudio giving "Cannot resolve method keyset()" error.

If i go to keys() definition, here they both are public and all: http://goloskok.com/u/2015-07-01_16-41-08.jpg

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the `@hide`    annotation

```
* @hide.
  */
        public Set<String> keySet() {
            return nameValuePairs.keySet();
        }
```

Comment: but WHY is it hidden?